# Usar retorno do prompt com operador ternário

Tags: javascript

Como posso usar o retorno dele direto nas expressões? Porque eu só consigo usar se for abrir o prompt 2 vezes.

Eu queria que, se na condição, o valor for o que eu quero, ele (o valor) caia na expressão direto, sem eu ter que abrir o prompt de novo, entendem?

```js
let promptValue = prompt('Valor') > 10 ? 'Valor do prompt aqui' : 'Não';
console.log(promptValue);
```

Como podem ver, no lugar do "Valor do prompt aqui" eu só conseguiria esse valor se eu por outro prompt, mas no caso eu quero o valor que eu coloquei no prompt da condição. Tem como isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `prompt` retorna sempre uma *String*, e não um número. Tens de usar `Number()` para converter em numero. Mais que isso precisas de guardar o valor numa variável para poderes usar como condição e opção nesse ternário.

```js
const val = Number(prompt('Valor'));
let promptValue = val > 10 ? val : 'Não';
console.log(promptValue);
```

Comment: Ah, isso que eu queria saber. Eu coloquei em string ali so pra exemplo mesmo, mas ele tem o retorno nesse val. Valeu Sergio, não sabia

Comment: Sérgio, eu vi de novo a sua resposta rs, agora que percebi. Por exemplo, sem criar uma variavel pra pegar o prompt, fazer diretamente mesmo, igual na pergunta, teria como? Ali vc armazena o prompt no val e depois cria outra variavel. Seria mais ou menos isso aqui mesmo: let promptValue = prompt('Valor') > 10 ? 'Valor do prompt aqui' : 'Não';
So que no lugar de 'Valor do prompt' eu ja colocaria direto o que ele retorna. Não é possível ne?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho não, o ternário não tem referência à condição dentro das opções. Podias fazer `let promptValue = ((val) => val > 10 ? val : 'Não')(Number(prompt('Valor')));`, mas isso é uma maneira complexa e disfarçada.

Comment: Entendi, show de bola! Obrigado pela explicação!